# Why would boilerplate unit tests in a boilerplate Cocoa Touch Framework project with a single Cocoapod dependency fail without even running?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods

Here are the step needed to reproduce:

(1) Using XCode 9.2, create a new Cocoa Touch Framework project called "Whatever" including Unit Tests.

(2) Close project and add the following podfile to the project folder.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Whatever' do
    pod 'Signals'
    # Signals is used, but any pod seems to produce the problem
end
```

(3) Run `pod setup` and `pod install`.

(4) Open Whatever.xcworkspace.

(5) Open the Test Navigator and run the boilerplate tests.

Not only do the tests fail, but the little diamonds in the line numbers fail to turn red, or any colour

[image]

What is happening here, please?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this question is a duplicate, but you likely need to add your test target to your Podfile. In this example, I assume it is WhateverTests.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Whatever' do
    pod 'Signals'
    # Signals is used, but any pod seems to produce the problem
end

target 'WhateverTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Signals'
end
```

After making this change, run `pod install`.

Comment: Thanks @CodeBender. I seem to be a serial offender for repeated questions recently, clearly my search game is weak

Comment: That seemed to work @CodeBender, thank you. Silly of me to forget to add the test target to the podfile.

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum Cool, it happens - not the most obvious thing to do